# Is there an equivalent of zdiff for zstandard

Tags: diff, compression, zstd

Is there an equivalent of the gzip utility [`zdiff(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zdiff), but for [`zstandard`](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/)?

I have not been able to find anything in the zstandard repository other than `zstdgrep` and `zstdless`.

Comment: `zdiff` is just a shell script. Here is my implementation of `zstddiff`: `zstddiff(){ diff <(zstdcat "$1") <(zstdcat "$2"); }`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is not yet, but soon to be. According to this recent issue [idea/request for help: zstd as a binary diff producer/patcher?](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/1935) in its Github repository, it is stated that:

> We will likely introduce a new cli command --diff-from=#. More on this soon.

Comment: That has OBVIOUSLY nothing to do with it. `zdiff` is not a "binary diff producer" as described in that issue, it just calls plain old `diff(1)` on two files compressed with gzip.